# Ruby - Instance variable value changing by itself

Tags: arrays, ruby, variables, iteration, instance-variables

An instance variable in my code keeps on having its value reassigned despite no commands for it to do so. Essentially, the variable is only called in twice: once, to assign its value at startup and then to copy its value to another variable. The code I am working on is a bit complex for me to post it here completely, but this is a basic rundown of it:

```
class Test
    def self.initialize
        @problem_var = [ ["1 2 3", "4 5 6"], ["a b c", "d e f"], ["bar", "foo"] ]
    end

    def self.main_method(parVar)
        data = @problem_var
        result = "Lorem"

        #Iterate through subarrays
        data.each do |dataBlock|

            #Some code here

            if condition then
                #The first subarray meets the condition

                char = dataBlock[1]

                #At this point char is equal to "4 5 6"
                #@problem_var still holds its original value of:
                # [ ["1 2 3", "4 5 6"], ["a b c", "d e f"], ["bar", "foo"] ]

                result = OtherModule.replace_six(char)

                #By this point, char is now equal to "4 5 7"
                #Curiously @problem_var is now equal to:
                # [ ["1 2 3, "4 5 7"], ["a b c", "d e f"], ["bar", "foo"] ]
            end
        end

        #More code here

        return result
    end 
end
```

Something weird happens to the variable right after `result` has a value assigned to it. Furthermore, this only seems to happen once so that if the code were to run again and alter that 7 to say... an 8, `@problem_var` would not be updated. Changing `@problem_var` to a constant has not been able to prevent it from being altered. I have mulled over this for the past two weeks and haven't been able to figure it out. Anyone know what could be happening?

**Edit:**
You guys were right! The issue was in OtherModule. I was using `gsub!` on the parameter variable that received `char`. Here's the simplified OtherModule code for future reference:

```
module OtherModule
    def replace_six(input)
        modified_string = "" 

        if condition(input) then
           #Input meets condition
           first_string = replace_numbers(input)

           #The following method doesn't really apply here
           second_string = replace_letters(first_string)

           modified_string = second_string
        end

        return modified_string
    end

    def replace_numbers(text)

        #Some code here

        #The following condition for numbers in `text`
        if condition(text) then
            text.gsub!("6", numberFunction)
            #numberFunction returns a string
        end
        return text
    end
end
```

Comment: Sounds like the replace_six method modifies the value passed to it

Comment: Share the code of `OtherModule.replace_six(char)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is most likely in `OtherModule.replace_six`.
If it uses `String#replace` method, then, String is mutated and its effect will be visible everywhere a reference to its has been kept.

---

If you do not have access to code of `OtherModule`, then, do this:

```
 result = OtherModule.replace_six(char.dup)
```

---

If you have access to code of `OtherModule`, then, change the implementation of `replace_six` such that it uses either `String#sub` or `String#gsub`, as they return a copy of modified string instead of mutating the original string.